# Line Break in Localizable.strings for MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, line-breaks, localizable.strings

How can I add line breaks in my language file for use in `MFMailComposeViewController`? The `\n` doesent work for me. A break with a normal klick on return key has the same result, no line breaks!

---

**My file:**

```
"Body_eMail"= "Hello, here is some text.\n\nLorem ipsum alsu.\n\nAnd some text, more...";
```

**I want:**

Hello,

here is some text. Lorem ipsum alsu.

And some text, more...

---

This works fine for UILabel (as @lawicko mentioned below) but when adding to a `MFMailComposeViewController` the `\n` characters are displayed inline, like below:

`Hello, here is some text.\n\nLorem ipsum alsu.\n\nAnd some text, more...`

What is the right way?

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: no.... its the same ... I have no idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First ensure your `MFMailComposeViewController` has `isHTML:YES` set.

```
MFMailComposeViewController *emailView = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
NSString *emailBody = NSLocalizedString(@"Email Body", @"");
[emailView setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];

[self presentModalViewController:emailView animated:YES];
```

In your `Localizable.strings` you must use the HTML `<br />` tag to produce line breaks.

```
"emailBody" = "Hello, here is some text.<br /><br />Lorem ipsum alsu.<br /><br />And some text, more...";
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Adding **\n** works if you display the text in the UITextView. It also works if you display the text in the UILabel if you set the appropriate [numberOfLines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/numberOfLines). I just tested it on iOS5 simulator and iPod with iOS 5.0.1.

Comment: Hi, the text is shown in an e-mail (no uilabel etc...)... to recommend the app... the \n doesnt work... ;-(

Comment: Do you use MFMailComposeViewController to send your emails?

Comment: Yes I do ;-)-(void)displayMailComposerSheet 
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [picker setSubject:NSLocalizedString(@"Betr",@"Bet")];
    // Set up recipients
    //NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@""]; 
    //[picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];
    NSString *emailSharing = NSLocalizedString(@"Bdy",@"Txt");
    // Fill out the email body text
    [picker setMessageBody:emailSharing isHTML:YES];
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];}

Comment: Sometimes `numberOfLines` is not enough - some set phrases which look bad when are split into different lines